# SQL Query to Show When Golfer Not Attached to an Event/Year

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am working on a school assignment that has downright stumped me for days. The task is to, using a view (VAvailableGolfers), populate a list box with Golfers who are not tied to a given event/year selected from a combo box. Here is the data in the tables:

[image: SQL Data]

The expected output on the form, then, would be:

- 2015 shows Goldstein available
- 2016 shows no one available
- 2017 shows both Goldstein and Everett available

so, in other words, where there isn't a record in TGolferEventYears for a golfer for a particular year

I have tried left joins, full outer joins, exists, not in, not exists, etc and I cannot seem to nail down the SQL to make it happen.

Here is the VB Form and the SQL backing it. I cannot figure out what to code in the view:

[image: VB Form]

"SELECT intGolferID, strLastName FROM vAvailableGolfers WHERE intEventYearID = " & cboEvents.SelectedValue.ToString

Here is the view, which I know isn't giving correct output:

```sql
select tg.intGolferID, strLastName, intEventYearID
from TGolferEventYears TGEY, TGolfers TG
Where tgey.intGolferID = tg.intGolferID 
and intEventYearID not IN
         (select intEventYearID
         from TEventYears
         where intEventYearID not in
               (select intEventYearID
               from TGolferEventYears))
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually approach this type of question by using a `cross join` to generate all possibly combination and then a `left join`/`where` to filter out the ones that already exist:

```
select g.intGolferID, g.strLastName, ey.intEventYearID
from TEventYears ey cross join
     TGolfers g left join
     TGolferEventYears gey
     on gey.intGolferID = g.intGolferID and
        gey.intEventYearID = ey.intEventYearID
where gey.intGolferID is null;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked beautifully. Gave me exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT tg.intGolferID, strLastName, tey.intEventYearID, tey.intEventYear
FROM TGolfers tg, TEventYears tey
WHERE tg.intGolferID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT tgey.intGolferID
    FROM TGolferEventYears tgey
    WHERE tgey.intEventYearID = tey.intEventYearID
)
```

### Explanation

Since you are trying to get combinations of data that is *not* in `TGolferEventYears`, you cannot use it in your outer-most `SELECT` as any of its columns would be NULL. Therefore, you need to `SELECT FROM` the tables that are the sources of that data, and going through each joined record, filter out the combinations that are in `TGolferEventYears`.

#### Main query

Select the data you need:

```sql
SELECT tg.intGolferID, strLastName, tey.intEventYearID, tey.intEventYear
```

...from `TGolfers`, cross join with `TEventYears`:

```sql
FROM TGolfers tg, TEventYears tey
```

...where the golfer ID does not exist in the following collection:

```sql
WHERE tg.intGolferID NOT IN ( ... )
```

#### Subquery

Select unique golfer IDs:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT tgey.intGolferID
```

...from `TGolferEventYears`:

```sql
FROM TGolferEventYears tgey
```

...where the year is the current year of the ***outer*** query:

```sql
WHERE tgey.intEventYearID = tey.intEventYearID
```

### Result

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| intGolferID | strLastName | intEventYearID | intEventYear |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
|           1 | Goldstein   |              1 |         2015 |
|           1 | Goldstein   |              3 |         2017 |
|           2 | Everett     |              3 |         2017 |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
```